# Facebook android session lifecycle

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I use LoginButton class from SDK 3 to manage facebook session. Now I wonder if there can be any reason for closing a session other than clicking "Log out" button by user?

In other words - can I be sure that unless user clicks "Log out" button, facebook session remains open "forever"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO!
In fact you have to reopen a session after an application is killed.
If you have a token cache available you don't have to show to the user the login dialog, and the session can be opened with that token.
Besides there is also the possibility that the token is expired, so the user will have to re-authenticate.

Comment: Thanks. Can I then make an assumption, that as long as user didn't log out, my session didn't expire and I didn't explicitly clear auth token (with closeAndClearTokenInformation()) I am able to reopen this session without prompting user for permission?

Comment: @MingLi Thanks :) Last concern I have - as long as my app remains alive, user don't log out, session don't expire, and I don't clear auth token, the session won't be closed (I will not receive a call to SessionStatusCallback with SessionState.CLOSED)?

Comment: The default strategy to persist the token uses SharedPreferences. This makes that the user can clear it in the app setting menu.

Comment: @GaRRaPeTa Does Facebook SDK automatically manage the token by the SharedPrederences?

Comment: From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/Session, Session#restoreSession() : "cachingStrategy the TokenCachingStrategy to use to load and store the token. If this is null, a default token cachingStrategy that stores data in SharedPreferences will be used". So, I believe that it does.